# Modifying Values to Specific Keys in Python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have created a dictionary *d* below and am looking for a dictionary with the *key* ('a','b','c') to have values 'd' and 'e'.

```
test = ['a','b','c','d','a','b','c','e','p','q','r','s']
test2= tuple(test)
d = {test2[i:i+3]:test2[i+3] for i in range(0,len(test2)-3,1)}
print(d)
```

The output is:

```
{('a', 'b', 'c'): 'e', ('b', 'c', 'd'): 'a', ('c', 'd', 'a'): 'b', ('d', 'a', 'b'): 'c', ('b', 'c', 'e'): 'p', ('c', 'e', 'p'): 'q', ('e', 'p', 'q'): 'r', ('p', 'q', 'r'): 's'}
```

The intended output is:

```
{('a', 'b', 'c'): ('d','e'), ('b', 'c', 'd'): 'a', ('c', 'd', 'a'): 'b', ('d', 'a', 'b'): 'c', ('b', 'c', 'e'): 'p', ('c', 'e', 'p'): 'q', ('e', 'p', 'q'): 'r', ('p', 'q', 'r'): 's'}
```

Question: Looking at the first comment, the *key* takes its most recent value *e* and so now I'm trying to change the code to achieve the desired output? Thanks.

Comment: "is why doesn't the key ('a','b','c') appear again the way I've constructed the dictionary?"  <-- What do you mean by this?  In this case, whichever comes last wins... it simply clobbers the previous entry.  Dictionary comprehension doesn't really lend itself to appending to keys.  I'd recommend two things: create `d` using defaultdict (`d = defaultdict(list)`), and loop through the data in a for loop and append the data into the entry (`test2[i:i+3].append(test2[i+3])`).

Comment: Can you show the intended output? It's quite hard to tell what this is meant to be doing

Comment: @JohnSzakmeister I see, that makes sense. Let me try your suggestion.

Comment: @JammyDodger I've added the intended output now. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Option 1:

This create d using defaultdict (d = defaultdict(list)).

It loops through the data in a for loop.  Multiple values are appended into a list

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)  # create list by default
for i in range(0,len(test2)-3):
  d[test2[i:i+3]].append(test2[i+3]) # append value into dictionary entry
                                     # which is a list 
                                     # since we used d = defaultdict(list)
```

Option 2: Similar in form to option 1, but uses normal dictionary with setdefault to have key entries be lists

```
d = {}
for i in range(0,len(test2)-3):
  d.setdefault(test2[i:i+3], []).append(test2[i+3])
```

Both Options Have the Same Output

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>,
            {   ('a', 'b', 'c'): ['d', 'e'],
                ('b', 'c', 'd'): ['a'],
                ('b', 'c', 'e'): ['p'],
                ('c', 'd', 'a'): ['b'],
                ('c', 'e', 'p'): ['q'],
                ('d', 'a', 'b'): ['c'],
                ('e', 'p', 'q'): ['r'],
                ('p', 'q', 'r'): ['s']})
```

Answer (score 0):

Heres a another solution you can try out as well:

```
from collections import defaultdict

test = ['a','b','c','d','a','b','c','e','p','q','r','s']

d = defaultdict(list)
while len(test) >= 4:
    *key, value = test[:4] # key -> a, b, c  value -> d
    d[tuple(key)].append(value)
    test = test[1:]

print(d)
# defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {('a', 'b', 'c'): ['d', 'e'], ('b', 'c', 'd'): ['a'], ('c', 'd', 'a'): ['b'], ('d', 'a', 'b'): ['c'], ('b', 'c', 'e'): ['p'], ('c', 'e', 'p'): ['q'], ('e', 'p', 'q'): ['r'], ('p', 'q', 'r'): ['s']})
```

The basic idea is that it keeps shrinking the list `test` until less than 4 items are left, and groups the first three items `(a, b, c)` into a tuple, then the last character `d` as a value.